# universal app do something after all page element load

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app, page-lifecycle

I'm developing an universal app but i have a problem with load events.

I have to initialize some textblocks whichare inside an hub controller, and since i have to initialize them i read a method which is like this:

```
    private void txtDescrArea_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtDescrArea = sender as TextBlock;
    }
```

Done for each TextBlock in my hub controller. It work, and they are initialized, my problem is that i have a method called Load() which fill their `.Text` properties, but i don't know where to put it.

The `public Pagename()` is not good because i have a value passed from the previous page wich is picked up in `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` (called after the initializecomponent).

Even `OnNavigatedTo` is good because i checked with `txtDescrArea_Loaded` that it's called after the `OnNavigatedTo`.

I also tryed with `Page_Loaded` or `Page_LayoutUpdated` but they both are called before the `txtDescrArea_Loaded` method.

Now my problem is, how can i call a method, and from where i can do it, if i want to want until all Elements in my page are loaded?

I hope i was clear, for any better explaination ask. Thanks you all

Comment: Do you always have the same number of text area controls? You can use the content rendered event if you're just assigning values. If that won't work (you really shouldn't make changes to your presentation layer once you've rendered everything), you can use a helper function to monitor status of the controls and call it from each control's Load event handler. If all required controls are loaded, then make your text assignments.

Comment: @mjw Yeah i thought too at using like an index which always increase his value until i have all done. but i would like to know if does exist a method which is invoked when all Loaded events are done, like the OnCreate on android :(

Comment: Noted, i'll remove the last comment so as not to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an await method with delay after initializing component :

private async void txtDescrArea_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        txtDescrArea = sender as TextBlock;
    }

best of luck !

Comment: must work but i was looking at an "optimized" solution. an arranged one is also the one i had to use :\